# Mike's father in My Own Private Idaho?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-own-private-idaho

In My Own Private Idaho, it is understandable that Mike's brother is also his father. But I always thought: how is that possible? Did I misunderstand something? Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Well, it is based on Shakespeare. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incest. Essentially, Richard (the older brother) had sex (consensually or otherwise) with their mother which resulted in her becoming pregnant with Mike. Thus making Richard both Mike's brother and father. James Russo, the actor who played Richard, was 17 years older than River Phoenix, the actor who played Mike - I believe that Gus Van Sant cast actors that far apart age-wise on purpose to drive home the fact that Richard was old enough to have fathered Mike.